# Python: Child class attribute not sticking

Tags: python-3.x, parent-child

I am trying to work with classes, but am still new to them. I am confused on how to both inherit attributes from the parent class, as well as initialize new attributes for the child class. I find that the parent attributes are callable, but not the child attributes that I define. Please see my code below:

```
import random
import hashlib
import base64
import requests
import json
import urllib3
import getpass

# Disable warning re: server certificate checking turned off
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

class vsa:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vsa_token = self.api_authentication()
        self.headers = {'Authorization': "Bearer " + self.vsa_token}
        self.url = "example.com"

    def api_authentication(self):
        while True: 
            username = input("Enter your username: ")
            password = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")

            vsa = "example.com/api/auth"
            random_integer = random.randint(5000, 50000)
            CoveredSHA256HashTemp_object = hashlib.sha256()
            CoveredSHA256HashTemp_object.update(('%s%s' % (password, username)).encode('utf-8'))
            CoveredSHA256HashTemp = CoveredSHA256HashTemp_object.hexdigest()
            CoveredSHA256Hash_object = hashlib.sha256()
            CoveredSHA256Hash_object.update(('%s%d' % (CoveredSHA256HashTemp, random_integer)).encode('utf-8'))
            CoveredSHA256Hash = CoveredSHA256Hash_object.hexdigest()
            CoveredSHA1HashTemp_object = hashlib.sha1()
            CoveredSHA1HashTemp_object.update(('%s%s' % (password, username)).encode('utf-8'))
            CoveredSHA1HashTemp = CoveredSHA1HashTemp_object.hexdigest()
            CoveredSHA1Hash_object = hashlib.sha1()
            CoveredSHA1Hash_object.update(('%s%d' % (CoveredSHA1HashTemp, random_integer)).encode('utf-8'))
            CoveredSHA1Hash = CoveredSHA1Hash_object.hexdigest()
            auth = "user=%s, pass2=%s, pass1=%s, rpass2=%s, rpass1=%s, rand2=%d, twofapass=:undefined" % (username, CoveredSHA256Hash, CoveredSHA1Hash, CoveredSHA1Hash, CoveredSHA256Hash, random_integer)
            encode = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(('%s' % auth).encode('UTF-8')).decode('ascii')
            headers = { 'Authorization' : 'Basic %s' %  encode }
            r = requests.get(vsa, headers=headers, verify=False)

            data = r.text

            parsed_data = json.loads(data)
            if parsed_data['ResponseCode'] == 0:
                print("\nVSA token successfully retrieved\n")
                vsa_token = parsed_data['Result']['Token']
                return vsa_token
            else:
                print("Unauthorized")


    def get_vsa_token(self):
        return self.vsa_token

class agents(vsa):

    def __init___(self):
        vsa.__init__(self)
        self.call = "/asetmgmt/agents"

    def get_agents(self):
        list_agents = []
        r = requests.get(self.url + self.call, headers=self.headers, verify=False)
        data = r.text
        parsed_data = json.loads(data)
        all_agents = parsed_data
        for agents in all_agents['Result']:
                    list_agents.append((agents['AgentName']))
        return list_agents

session = agents()
print(session.call)
```

The final command - `print(session.call)` gives me the following output:

```
AttributeError: 'agents' object has no attribute 'call'
```

However, I have taken (what I believe to be) the pertinent pieces of this code and ran it through PythonTutor, and see that the call attribute is being initialized?

[PythonTutor Link to Code](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=class%20vsa%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__init__%28self%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.vsa_token%20%3D%20%22test%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.headers%20%3D%20%7B'Authorization'%3A%20%22Bearer%20%22%20%2B%20%22test%22%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.url%20%3D%20%22test-url%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Aclass%20agents%28vsa%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__init__%28self%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vsa.__init__%28self%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.call%20%3D%20%22test%20call%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Asessions%20%3D%20agents%28%29%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=10&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

I am at a loss for what I am doing wrong. I have found that I can initialize the variable outside of the `agents.__init__(self)` block and this works fine:

```
class agents(vsa):

    call = "/assetmgmt/agents"

    def __init___(self):
        vsa.__init__(self)
```

but now it is something conceptual that is bothering me. Am I foolish in the way I am structuring this? How would you structure better?

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Comment: Your `agents` class has a typo. Instead of `__init__` (with two leading and trailing underscores), you've defined an `__init___` method, with three underscores at the end. That method never gets called, so it never sets the attribute you're trying to print out later on. The inherited `vsa.__init__` method does get called, since it's not overridden in the child class (since the typoed name is not the same).

Comment: Holy cow. I never would have spotted that. I clearly didn't make that mistake when I transferred it over the the PythonTutor test case. I fixed this in my actual code and, of course, it runs just fine. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Blckknght who provided me with the solution, which is fix the typo I made...

`__init___` !=  `__init__`

It's always the simple things that are overlooked. I am glad I posted a question here rather than continuously debugging and trying other solutions (which I did for probably 30 treacherous minutes).

Thanks!